# S3 File Management Skeleton - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3

I am looking for a skeleton framework to manage files on S3 utilizing php/mysql. My hope is that someone has already created it and I can pull from it instead of building it all myself.

I am thinking something like dropbox.com

Anyone know of a open source solution that I can pull from?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework offers very robust AWS components, including S3. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html